# How i can add folder in filedepot using a custom module (without rules)

Tags: 7, entities, hooks, nodes

I want to create a module that adds a FileDepot folder, in this module I want the user chooses a name for the folder and I want the Parent Folder will by default "Top Level Root", I began to create this module but I'm stuck, here is my code :

```
function custombutton_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['custombutton/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('My form'),
    'page callback' => 'custombutton_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;}

function custombutton_form() {
return drupal_get_form('custombutton_my_form');}
function custombutton_my_form($form_state) {
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
$form['name']['first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => "Please enter your first name.",
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
);
$form['name']['last'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['year_of_birth'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => "Year of birth",
    '#description' => 'Format is "YYYY"',
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
);
return $form;}
function custombutton_my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'];
if ($year_of_birth && ($year_of_birth < 1900 || $year_of_birth > 2000)) {
    form_set_error('year_of_birth', 'Enter a year between 1900 and 2000.');}}

function custombutton_my_form_insert($node){
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'filedepot_folder';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->name = first;
$node->title = last;
$node->filedepot_folder_desc[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'This is private folder of author user.';
$node->parentfolder = TopLevelRoot;
$node->inherit = 0;
node_save($node);}
function custombutton_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you stuck? What's happening? What's not happening? What should be happening? And so on

Comment: i want know how i use hook_insert() to add a content type , i want to know how i can add filedepot folder using a custom module (hook_insert) i dont understand how i do this

Comment: `hook_insert()` is not for adding content types, it's invoked in response to a node being created whose type is provided by the implementing module